# 2sxc global content types / views

Tags: 2sxc

suspect I already know the answer to this question but..

Client has just started another portal in DNN and wants all the same content types and views in the new portal wanted to avoid duplicating all of the content structure and templates in 2sxc

is there any way to have DNN install wide content types and views?

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, but this is a sophisticated issue - like level 400. It's done using ghost content-types http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/ghost-content-types-advanced-dynamic-data-content

Fortunately there's a tutorial: http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/sharing-dynamic-content-type-definitions-across-portals-and-apps-with-ghost-content-types-400

Good luck :)